# Blazor SSR - Browser error when routing to different pages with docker (https-portal)

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, blazor-server-side

I'm currently trying to run a .NET core 3 (preview 8) SSR-blazor project in docker. The pages seem to load fine until you start navigating, uses `NavLink`, which gives me the following error in the browser console:

> Error: There was an exception invoking 'NotifyLocationChanged' on
>   assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server'. For more details
>   turn on detailed exceptions in 'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'

My current docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: '2'

services:

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - "database"

  database:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest-ubuntu"
    environment:
      MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD: "Hidden"
      ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"

  https-portal:
    image: steveltn/https-portal:1
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    links:
      - app
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WEBSOCKET: true
      - DOMAINS: 'somesite.com -> http://app:5000'
#      - STAGE: 'local'
      - STAGE: 'staging'
#      - STAGE: 'production'
```

I thought it had something to do with the `- WEBSOCKET: true` environment or `app.UseForwardedHeaders();` in code. But the results are the same.

Edit 1:

So I added the following code in my startup and it started working:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardedHeaders =
                ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
});
```

Got it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Edit 2:

Nevermind it stopped working. Seems like it only works the first time or after a long time of inactivity. After that, I get the same error.

Edit 3:

So I created a brand new Blazor (preview 8) project with the same docker structure, and what's weird is that it works in this project. I tried comparing this new project with mine (made in preview 5 but upgraded over time), however, I could not find any big major differences. I'm currently migrating some old code over to the new project and see when it's not working anymore. I hope this gives me the answer because I'm absolutely lost at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working. So i had to add the following to my startup

```
app.Use((ctx, next) =>
{
    ctx.Request.Scheme = "https";
    return next();
});
```

Now the routing works perfect